# Why I cannot delete an account in 24 hours?

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

I deleted a profile yesterday. The system claimed it was to be deleted in 24 hours. However, I see the following message today.

> This account is scheduled to be deleted 5 mins ago. To cancel deletion, click here.

Why the account isn't deleted on time? 5 mins after the deadline?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deletions do not take place the moment the 24 hours is up. There is a scheduled task that runs once an hour that checks for profiles past the scheduled deletion time and deletes them all in a batch process. If your countdown is past the 24-hour mark, it will be deleted as soon as that task runs next.

There are also circumstances which can cause that deletion to be halted and placed in a queue for manual review by staff, but your profile doesn't meet any of those criteria.

Comment: If your account is held up for manual review, your deletion notice may show a date a long time in the past - this is not a bug. If it's been more than one week since that date, contact SE.